# Sleep, Loop, or What in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a game loop and it basically is this: `function game(){init();setInterval(draw, 30);}` but when a player wins I want to call `Win()` which clears the interval and restart. What's the best way to tackle this in javascript? Since the `setInterval()` is asynch I've already fallen out of `game()` by this point. So do I add a busy loop: `function game(){while(1){init();setInterval(draw, 30);while(!Win);}}`? There's no good way to `sleep()` currently is there? Is there a way to call `game()` inside `Win()` without making the call stack of arbitrary size? What's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: You can set the timer to a variable such as `var timer = setInterval(...)` then clear the timer by calling `clearInterval(timer)`. However, in my opinion, anytime you're using a timer you should consider the possibility that there's another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Can't you call `win()` from wherever you handle your game's logic? `draw()` looks like the place, but the name doesn't imply it

Comment: you could use `delay(milliseconds)`

Comment: @JSelser you're right it is in draw(). The logic was light enough I didn't bother with anything else. In the real code game() is actually called init() as well but I was just throwing up a minimal example. But my question about the call stack enters at this point. Doesn't it grow, and can I avoid that?

Comment: @nateyolles I'm clearing in Win() but your comment doesn't really address the question. How would you reboot after such a clear without growing call stack or busy looping?

Comment: @James111 I'm using light code so I'm not loading jQuery just for delay(). But that would be a solution I believe, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use named interval:

```
var time;
function game(){
     init();
     time = setInterval(function (){
          draw();
     }, 30);
}

win(){
    if(time){
        clearInterval(time); // clear the interval
        game(); // start the game again.
    }
}
```

Now you have to call this win function, whenever user wins and start the game.

Comment: Yeah but Win() is called inside draw()... So isn't it adding to the call stack?

Comment: Then you have to have a condition which puts an eye on the condition which turns to true when user wins.

Comment: That would not be added to stack if you have a proper condition.

Comment: Isn't that functionally my busy loop suggestion though? duh...just figured it out: Just make the busy loop it's own interval and I'll only need to check it every second or so and it's not quite so "busy". THAT would be the best way to do this in javascript correct? If that or similar could you update the answer so I can accept?

Comment: @Black ensure that you're only calling `win` when appropriate; you're keeping a closure reference to `win` within draw, and calling `win` with a predicate. Your stack will increase by whatever `win( )` will increase it by, but your actual callstack is going to be drained at the bottom of `draw`, and a new one will take over, in the new interval period. JS game-engine or otherwise polling loops are'nt easy to initially grasp. But think of it like an implicit sleep at the bottom of draw, where the callstack is gone and the browser gets the thread for render/IO work, then gives you a new stack.

Comment: @Black your busy loop will actually lock the thread, and thus never give it back to the browser, and thus never allow you to render (or enter input, or even allow you to refresh the page in certain browsers). Rely on the implicit sleep and the callback. Ideally with `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setTimeout` || `setInterval`, but let the stack drain, quickly and without trying to keep the thread locked, nonetheless.

Comment: @Norguard So each interval gets its own call stack? So my suggestion above would work then? `game(){ init(); setInterval(draw,30); setInterval(checkRebootGame,1000); }`

Comment: @Black theoretically, yes...  ...you may have several frames that go by, in that case, where the game should already be over. And you'll need a global `shouldReboot` that gets set to `true` or whathaveyou, if you're relying on the `checkReboot`. A better solution might be to do something like `var pid = setInterval(tick, 1000/60); function tick () { var isOver = draw(); if (isOver) { win(pid); } }` And not each `interval`. That'd be a wrong way of thinking about it. The call-stack exists until there are no more synchronous calls on the stack. `set(Interval|Timeout)`, AJAX, Promises... async

Comment: @Black when the host environment decides it (the browser's tab-manager, or whatever is hosting the JS machine) it starts up the execution context for whatever stack of synchronous calls has been scheduled next. If you had previously fired a timeout, then it will call the function that was registered in that timeout, and it will run until the stack has been exhausted; at that point, the thread reverts back to the host for all of the browser/server/app-container stuff. The host will then set off the next registered stack in JS, et cetera.

Comment: @Norguard So my way of thinking of the stack: `game->pid = tick` and every frame: `tick->draw` and on the final draw call of the game `tick->draw->win->clearInterval(pid)---(game has long returned by this point)---->game->pid = tick`  .......etc.  *is that correct?*

Comment: @Black assume `next` is the name of the function in my setInterval example (it’s been taken out given a name, and passed as a reference): `game->pid=setInterval(next) ... ... next()->over=draw() === false ... ... next()->over=draw() === false ... ... next()->over=draw() === true win()->clearInterval(pid); restart()->game()` Each `... ...` is the exhaustion of synchronous calls, and the eventual rescheduling of another entry, into `next`

Comment: @Norguard I think we're on the same page now. Thank you for baby-stepping me through this answer. This is my first javascript project and I have my hands full reading up on closures and reworking my C into pass-by-reference compatible code. Sadly, I can't really shoot any smaller than I currently am. C->Javascript *big jump!*

Comment: @Black synchronous polling loops are the worst thing in the world to replicate in JS, aside from using async callbacks to break up recursion, before you blow up your stack (pretty big, these days, bt still). The easier ones are I/O generated or a server request/response. Anything that pokes the JS and tells it to move. Whatever you pass in as the listener/handler, basically becomes the `main` for the next stack, except that it still has references to all of the things that it could lexically see in its parent scope, from the previous stack (pseudo-"pointers", if you will).

Comment: @Norguard Actually that makes sense. Using event capturing for processing my restart instead of only direct flow control. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Paradigm bound I guess. Thanks a ton. I see lots of ways to solve this problem now.